# How to Fix Resolutions Globally in Menu by Using NGUI in UNITY3D?

Tags: menu, unity-game-engine, ngui

I need a menu screen. The menu screen contains **Buttons** , **Background**, **sliced Sprite**.

I have done this, but I face one problem: when I change the resolution of menu screen, it changes the background.

Initially I was using a resolution of **800 X 480**. I have changed this to **600 X 1024**, but the **Buttons** and **Background** have changed but are not set globally. How can I fix my resolution problems by using **ngui** in **UNITY3D**?

Comment: If you look at your UI Root, what is the Maximum Height set to?

Comment: ui Root Max Height setting is 1024

Answer (score 0):

There are a few good discussions about this:
You can start here:

http://www.tasharen.com/forum/index.php?topic=1398.0

also, check out the UiAnchor example by NGUI:
http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=619

There are a few more discussions you can easily find

Comment: thanx for giving links, but this is set to 2 screen resolutions but i needed to set all screen resolutions plz help me very urjent.